# onKeyup won't catch last letter for filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, shuffle, onkeyup

I am using shufflejs located here:
http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/
I am having problems catching the last letter only when a user types fast. Example: 
User types "pug" and "Lenovo Computer", "Mac Computer", "Pug Dog" and "Purple Chair" come up because they all have "pu" in it. Also if I hit backspace 3 times to delete the word "pug" in the search box, it doesn't default to the original position. I have to hit it 4 times, even though the search is clear.

This does not occur, and everything works as desired, if the user types slow. 
I've tried onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeychange, and oninput but nothing seems to fix it.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure I missed some small detail but I can't catch it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4" data-groups="electronic" data-title="Lenovo Computer">
    <img src="image/lenovoLap.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        <figcaption class="picture-item__title">Lenovo Computer</figcaption>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" data-groups="electronic" data-title="Mac Computer">
    <img src="image/macBook.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        <figcaption class="picture-item__title">Mac Computer</figcaption>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" data-groups="pet" data-title="Pug Dog">
    <img src="image/pugDog.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        <figcaption class="picture-item__title">Pug Dog</figcaption>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" data-groups="furniture" data-title="Purple Chair">
    <img src="image/PurpleChair.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        <figcaption class="picture-item__title">Purple Chair</figcaption>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

gridContainer = $('#shuffleContainer');
var sizer = gridContainer.find('.col-md-4');

$('.js-shuffle-search').on('keyup', function () {
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function ($el, shuffle) {

        // Only search elements in the current group
        if (shuffle.group !== 'all' && $.inArray(shuffle.group, $el.data('groups')) === -1) {
            return false;
        }

        var text = $.trim($el.find('.picture-item__title').text()).toLowerCase();
        return text.indexOf(val) !== -1;
    });
});
```

Comment: Try using `input` event.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan My apologies, I'm still a little bit new to JS. I tried   $('.js-shuffle-search').on('input', function () {... and it didn't work, Is that what you mean?